# Set a filled sqlite default database in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, chromium, tidesdk

I have written an app using javascript , it uses websql as its database, when I open it in chrome everything works fine. it uses a filled database table which is like a dictionary. I mean the app needs the database to run correctly. The problem is that when I want to use it on another computer I need to transfer the database to where chrome databases are and rename it to the currently created sqlite file that is created by running the program first (with database not found error of course). The question is  how can I automate this? , I've tried deskshell and tidesdk but it still doesn't work. tidesdk doesn't even render the css correctly. deskshell doesn't create the app and the database problem is still unresolved.

Comment: Do you need the contents of the database or just the structure? If you only need the structure you might consider making an "install script" that makes the sql setup you need.

Comment: @user1822921 did you manage to create an .exe with sqlite bachend in deskshell?